# Many to one hash function

Tags: hash, cryptography, hashcode

I don't know exactly what to call it and this is the closest thing that I can think of

What I'm looking for is a function that takes an array of strings and returns a hash string like the following

```js
const inputs = [str_1, str_2 ...... str_n]

const hash = generate_hash(inputs)
```

And then another function that takes 2 arguments, the previously generated hash and a random string and returns true or false if the provided string is a member of the inputs array that is used to generate the hash

```js
const random_str = "random"

const is_in_inputs = check_str(hash, random_str)
```

This could even be an encryption algorithm with multiple keys and only those keys could decrypt the encrypted string

I don't care about the security and stuff, I just want something that gets the job done

If such thing already exists then point me in the right direction and if not then tell me how can I implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [Bloom Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). It will never return a false negative (i.e. if it says "random" is not in the hash, it isn't), but i can return false positives.

All fixed-sized structures that do this will be probabilistic. They will either have false positives or false negatives. (You can get false negatives without false positives [just by making this a cache instead of a hash](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6596/a-probabilistic-set-with-no-false-positives).) The only way to make this fully deterministic (no false results) is to let it grow without bound. The most obvious implementation would be to have `generate_hash` unambiguously encode all the elements (serialize to length-value for example) and then gzip the result. But this is no longer a "hash." It's just an encoding.

If it were possible to do this in fixed space, you could use it to infinitely compress data, which is impossible. Like with so many things in this space, the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) stops us.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your answer, I did a little bit of research on bloom filters and it's really close to what I'm looking for but as yourself mentioned it is not fully deterministic, now my question is that if all input strings be the same length (and we know the length) and we know the quantity of the inputs as well, with the mentioned conditions is there any way to make something fully deterministic or is it still impossible to do that?

Comment: Totally possible; the hash may just be enormous. See my description of an implementation above. You can also assign every sequence of bytes to their bit position in the hash. So to encode 8-bit strings (one byte), you would need a 256-bit (32-byte) hash where each bit represents the presence of one of the bytes. This is the smallest possible deterministic hash (of course for fewer than 32 entries, just storing them is better). If you know more about the legal combinations of values, you can do better, but your hash can be no smaller than then number of combinations.

Comment: For a very specific version of the problem, there may be a solution that meets your needs, but you'll need to explain the full details. If you can't publish the full problem here, we can discuss consulting. (But what you want may not be mathematically possible.)

Comment: thanks a lot, what I've been trying to do was to make a compression algorithm but the fact that "the hash can be no smaller than then number of combinations" answers all my questions, as yourself mentioned it is not mathematically possible, thanks again for your time